# Rake doc:rails errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, documentation, rake

Trying to generate Rails API documentation, but running into errors:

```
$ rake doc:rails
rake aborted!
undefined method `task' for #<DummyApp::Application:0x00000100dd14d0>

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
MacBook-Pro-van-Joris-Ooms:dummy_app joris$ rake doc:rails --trace
rake aborted!
undefined method `task' for #<DummyApp::Application:0x000001023b1ea8>
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks'
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/Users/joris/Desktop/Projects/Rails/dummy_app/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `block in run'
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.9.0/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Had something similar earlier, where I had to downgrade my Rake (0.9) back to 0.8.7. I upgraded my gems since though; should I just downgrade again or is there a way to fix this and keep using Rake 0.9?

**UPDATE**:

After downgrading to Rake 0.8.7:

```
s$ rake doc:rails
(in /Users/joris/Desktop/Projects/Rails/dummy)
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant RAKEVERSION
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant WINDOWS
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:404: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY_TASK_ARGS
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:452: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:960: warning: already initialized constant RUBY_EXT
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:964: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1033: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1242: warning: already initialized constant ARRAY_METHODS
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1245: warning: already initialized constant MUST_DEFINE
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1249: warning: already initialized constant MUST_NOT_DEFINE
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1253: warning: already initialized constant SPECIAL_RETURN
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1259: warning: already initialized constant DELEGATING_METHODS
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1569: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1575: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1612: warning: already initialized constant FileList
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1638: warning: already initialized constant EARLY
/Users/joris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1968: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_RAKEFILES
rake aborted!
stack level too deep
```

Using @Zabba's approach:

```
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
```

after editing the Rakefile.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rake 0.9.0 has this problem.
To fix it, either downgrade to rake 0.8.7 or continue to use rake 0.9.0 and add the following just before the `My_app_name::Application.load_tasks` in `Rakefile` in the root of your app's directory:

```
#in case there is an error "undefined method `task'", add this (rake 0.9.0 has this bug)
module ::My_app_name
  class Application
    include Rake::DSL
  end
end

module ::RakeFileUtils
  extend Rake::FileUtilsExt
end

#code added above this line    
My_app_name::Application.load_tasks
```

Comment: Thanks. However, is there any reason I shouldn't use 0.8.7 instead? What does 0.9 offer more (except, uh, errors) than 0.8.7?

Comment: I had to specify the correct version of the Rake gem in my Gemfile. Apparently it was using 0.8.7, which I somehow can't uninstall (gives errors..). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `Gemfile` and then use `bundle exec rake` instead:

```
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
```